Could for ability
I can repair it today
He said that he could repair it that day
Can you explain why we change "can" to "could" since as far as I'm concerned "could" is only used for general possibility in the past such as "I could swim when I wad little"

"Could" is the past tense of "can". When changing direct to indirect speech you need to change the tense.

"I could help her when she came this afternoon". Is this correct or I should have use was able to?

You changed "today" to "that day" in the reported speech version. But if "that day" is still "today" at time of speaking, it could have been rendered as EITHER #1) He said that he could repair it today OR #2) He said that he can repair it today. And I don't think anyone could (can?! :) make a case for claiming that #1 and #2 there might have different meanings. It's just a stylistic choice.

My main question is if could in the past can refer to specififc ability or possibility for example " I could help her when she came in" it's fine or there is a neds for was able to?

"I could help her when she came in" could in principle mean [If she had asked for help] when she came in [yesterday], I would have been able to help [but because she didn't ask, I didn't actually help]. But in practice we'd use the Perfect form I could have helped if we actually didn't, and I was able to help if we did help.

“I don't think anyone could (can?! :) make a case for claiming that #1 and #2 there might have different meanings.“ Okay, @FumbleFingers, challenge accepted. #2 describes an ongoing situation, so I still hope that he can. #1 describes a completed situation, so maybe since saying he could, he’s had a heart attack and been rushed to the hospital

@PaulTanenbaum: You're right. Essentially, if he still has the ability to do it is on a par with my if "that day" is still "today" at time of speaking. We can only use can if both those "background facts" remain true at time of speaking. Which doesn't imply the could/can alternatives always mean different things. Just that in specific [contrived?] contexts they might have different meanings or applicability. But usually not.

The past tense of can is could:

He said he could repair it that day.
He says he can repair it today.

I had to also change that day to today for the sentence to make sense, but there shouldn't be any confusion.
If your sentence had said, He said he could repair it today, that has a different meaning because it makes it uncertain.
